# How to figure out which JButton was pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Currently making a program to display data, and I want to have the data editable by clicking on it. How would I figure out which button was pressed? I can't look at what the value is because the value could be anything. This is how I am adding them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < indexOrder.size(); i++)
{
    colName = new JLabel(colNames.get(indexOrder.get(i))+": ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    colName.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
    rowPane.add(colName);

    colData = new JButton(custData.get(indexOrder.get(i)));
    colData.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    colData.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    colData.setBackground(Color.white);
    rowPane.add(colData);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the part where you handle the `Event`'s for button presses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made another array for Strings, used setName() to set each buttons name to it's index, and put the names into the new array as Strings. Now I can use getName(), convert it back to an integer, and figure out which button was pressed by comparing it to my original indexOrder array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by checking the source of the `ActionEvent` using `getSource()` :

```
buttonA = new JButton("A");
buttonA.addActionListener(this);

buttonB = new JButton("B");
buttonB.addActionListener(this);

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getSource().equals(buttonA) ? "A was cliked" : "B was clicked");
}
```